# How to access this element with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have this autogenerated code in HTML.

How can I get the span class icon with CSS to modify it when hover.

I can not call `.icon` because I will change all the icons on the page and I just want to change this one.

```
<li class="level1 item156">
       <a class="carpo1 level1" href="/carpooling" title="carpoT">
           <span>
               <span class="icon" style="background-image: url('http://thebackpackerweb.estrategic.es/images/EntregaProyecto/Icon_carpooling_h.png');"></span>
           carpooling
           </span>
        </a>
 </li>
```

Comment: Assign an id to this span

Comment: I am not able to do that. It is autogenerated code in Joomla 3.1 for an icon in a menu.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would maybe go with

```
.item156 .icon {
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: Working perfectly, I will accept your answer as soon as stackoverflow let me do it. Thanks again!!!

Answer (score 0):

This will work as you expect :

```
.item156 .icon:hover {
    background: blue;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Give this particular span class an id and then change it according to your requirement.